# CodeIgniter: Auth library or custom for FileMaker

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, filemaker

I have a site with the following requirements:

• register into MySQL, send activation email to user

• once activation email clicked, record activated and moved into FileMaker

From then on, login, password resets and updating details will be done directly on the filemaker database

There is already a FileMaker PHP API but my question is about authentication. There is obviously no out-of-the-box Auth library that will do exactly as above so I can either write my own or try and hack an existing library, such as TankAuth or IonAuth,

I haven't used either of those existing libraries before so I'm unsure of how much I'll need to hack without getting into it. Has anyone been down this road before?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done anything with FileMaker, but I recently had a similar project where I had a db update after activation (via email).

I used IonAuth which supports the activation email out of the box and you can simply add the extra functionality to the controller method you are using as the activation point. Presumably you can use the FileMaker API if the activation is successful and the rest is out of CodeIgniter's hands? Or did you require the auth package to be able to directly deal with FileMaker?

Comment: Yes, basically the Auth package will be dealing with FileMaker, aside from the initial registration/activation email. So login/reset pass and updating details will be done on FileMaker directly.

Comment: Is there a driver for FileMaker that can be used by CodeIgniter's active record/db classes?

Comment: In that case, my answer is probably not very useful - apologies - whichever auth package you go with you will probably end up having to rewrite the majority of the model to get the methods working with FM